# I want collect all characters and events that end with a certain text?

Tags: python, regex, perl, collections, splunk

I want to collect all data before a specified text or that ends with it, I have tried the following:

```
   .{30}Value_*|.{55}Value2_*
```

But you have to specify how many characters you want to collect before the specified ending text, I want to just collect all of them (Note that Im dealing with Python/Perl regexes here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
"(.+?)Value_*|(.+?)Value2_*"
```

Without knowing exactly what your data looks like I can't get more specific.  To break it down: `.+` matches one or more characters, while `?` makes it non-greedy, so it doesn't consume the entire line at once, and finally the parentheses capture the match (in Python at least).

Comment: Why not make the `2` optional, and then ditch the alternation?

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? I'm not clear what the point of the trailing `_*` (zero or more underscores) is, but won't

```
^(.*)Value
```

do what you need?

Comment: Hi @Borodin, yes it will, the trailing _*, is in face a Splunk only wildcard that you can include as part of your search query, I was mixing it up with the regex thinking it would work, so I got confused, but it sees to me yours works fine but how is it different from (.+) ??

Thanks

Comment: @IAML: Then what you want is `^(.*)Value2?_`. There is no need to match the trailing characters. `.+` requires "one or more" while `.*` requires "zero or more", so in this case the two are mostly equivalent. You could omit the `^` anchor because a search will start at the start of the string by default and `.` will match anything, but it describes the purpose of the pattern better with it present.